# How to call a user control in a client web part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online, office-365, user-controls

I'm trying to call a user control (.ascx) in a client web part that I've created, knowing that I need to do that in a provider hosted app.
Can someone give me a helpful tutorial please? What should I make in the client web part to call the page.ascx ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. First you should register the `ascx` file in the Markup of your webpart

```
<%@ Register Src="~/_controltemplates/15/Folder/Page.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="PageAscx" %>
```

Then add the control using

```
<uc1:PageAscx runat="server" id="PageUC1" />
```

Comment: thanks Hashim ,but should I put both of this  lines in the my webpart.aspx ??

Comment: Yes. Both line goes into your web part markup